# How to block multiple web request using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need help to lock more than one web request

I am developing a billing system where I give option for saving common configurations.so at a time only one use can save his own configuration.

so now my problem is if more than one user click on submit configuration button only one user can submit configuration other will have to wait till complete the first one

How can I do this in PHP?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You totally lost me.  Do you want each user to have a configuration?  If so, MySQL is pretty durn good at managing locking rows as needed to run a single INSERT/UPDATE query.  If you have multiple queries, use transactions.  If you're trying to make some kind of singleton configuration where multiple users can modify a single configuration, let us know, because that would be a separate problem entirely.

Comment: 1. LOCK TABLES table_name WRITE
2. run query
3. UNLOCK TABLES

Comment: Locking tables for web users isn't a very good idea. You never know when a user will just close his browser and walk away without saving.

Comment: guys please look at the situation I explained below the answer

Comment: the system is tenant base system.so each user have their own tenant.but each time load only one big file so it takes more CPU resources if 2 users commit changes simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

If each use can have their set of common configurations, why restrict others users?

Now, I understand there will be situations where you need to give only one use access(modifying a shared configuration).

Any sort of locking over the web has to be very cautious. I would suggest you keep an entry in a table in your db that user A is modifying the configuration at present(Get a lock).

When user B tries to open a configuration for editing, check when A tried to lock it. If lock was before a timeout period(say 10 mins) grant lock to A. This will ensure you don't end up permanantly locking a resource. If use A still holds a valid lock, notify user B accordingly.

Javascripts can warn user A about his lock expiring and renew it if required.

Comment: here is the original situation.I provide option to users to save their changes automatically by every 5 minutes.now I also give users a button lets say Commit button.so once one user click on commit button to commit all his changes meantime other user can not submit commit request by clicking on commit button. so how can I implement this situaltion so that only one user at a time can commit changes.

Comment: By keeping a locks table, as i explained in the answer. Not only should your second use not be able to commit at that time, he should not be able to open for reading itself. Otherwise when you allow him to save, second user would overwrite change by first user. Implementing changes only to parts isn't an easy task.

Comment: Readup on version control systems. This is what things like svn, git provide. Understanding how they work would help you build a better system.

Comment: then what is the best way to do if not use LOCK

Comment: Use a lock, just not a table lock. What part did you not understand?

Comment: the system is tenant base system.so each user have their own tenant.but each time load only one big file so it takes more CPU resources if 2 users commit changes simultaneously.SO how can I lock multiple request by not using table lock

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a database for this sort of thing. Each user should have their own record in the database so that each record is unique. When a user submits the form, their record ID will be associated with it so that you don't have conflicts.